# how can I import a kjar zip file in business central as a project

Tags: drools

I have downloaded the drools project as a zip file from business central. Now I am trying to import the zip in a business central which is setup in different system. I did not find any option where I can directly import it as zip file. It is only showing the option to provide the GIT URL which I don't want to. Can anyone suggest me the procedure to import the zip file in business central(I am using Drools 7.59.0)?